# how to post an image from a url via javascript / ajax without file dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, base64, multipartform-data

I'm trying to follow some API documentation which provides the following example:

```
$("#submit").click(function () {
var data = new FormData();
var files = $('#fileUpload').get(0).files;
if (files.length > 0) {
    data.append("attachment[file]", files[0]);
    data.append("mediaExtension", "jpg");

}
$.ajax({
     type: "post",
     url: "http://[ur]/api/Interaction/InteractionCreateLocationResultAsMedia",
    data: data,
    mimeType: "multipart/form-data",
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    success: function (data) {
        //do stuff
    },
    error: function (data, resultstatus, xhr) {
        alert("api call failed" + xhr);
    }
});
```

However, I am not using a file upload to create the image. The image is actually being created from html5 canvas. I can successfully convert the canvas to base64 data and submit it to my server, at which point it returns a url to where the image resides on my server - so I want to pass that URL (or maybe the base64 data) on to the API using the sample code above, but when I use the method below, I have a feeling it is not working, because in the data returned to me from the API, the "MediaData" key value is null.

Anyone know the proper way to pass my image on to this API?

Comment: If you can get a blob instead of base64 string you can just replace `files[0]` with it. `data.append("attachment[file]", theblob);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out - the answer was to create a blob as @Musa mentioend. I used the following method:

```
var imgSrc = $('.image-container').find('img').attr('src');

var dataURLToBlob = function(dataURL) {
    var BASE64_MARKER = ';base64,';
    if (dataURL.indexOf(BASE64_MARKER) == -1) {
      var parts = dataURL.split(',');
      var contentType = parts[0].split(':')[1];
      var raw = decodeURIComponent(parts[1]);

      return new Blob([raw], {type: contentType});
    }

    var parts = dataURL.split(BASE64_MARKER);
    var contentType = parts[0].split(':')[1];
    var raw = window.atob(parts[1]);
    var rawLength = raw.length;

    var uInt8Array = new Uint8Array(rawLength);

    for (var i = 0; i < rawLength; ++i) {
      uInt8Array[i] = raw.charCodeAt(i);
    }

    return new Blob([uInt8Array], {type: contentType});
}

var apiData = new FormData();
apiData.append( "attachment[file]", blob);

$.ajax({
  url: submissionURL,
  type: "post",
  dataType: 'json', //return response as json
  mimeType: "multipart/form-data",
  cache: false,
  contentType: false,
  processData: false,
  data: apiData,
  error: function(data,resultstatus,xhr) {
    console.error("error:",data,resultstatus,xhr);
 },
  success: function(){
    //
  }
});
```